# Change model And database table name in Laravel

Tags: laravel, database-connection, laravel-artisan, has-many, laravel-relations

I want to change my model name and its database table name in a Laravel project, but I've connected other models with relationships. So now I want to know if there is any way or artisan command to change it, so it does not make problems for its connection?

Comment: you can set per model the table or the connexion to use via protected attributes of the model: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#table-names

Comment: If you use phpstrom framework, you can right click name and refactor when change name it's change all where it is